# Строковое представление чисел в стиле ООП

Tags: java, ооп

Нужно реализовать представление чисел такое, что если число дробное 14.4 , то оно и должно так отображаться, а если целое получается как 14.0 то отображать просто 14. Проверка на %10 нельзя, нужно в стиле ООП решить. В классе число храниться как int, т.е. 14.4 хранится как 144. Ещё раз "**Реализовать отображение, т.е. строковое представление оценки в ООП–стиле, а не через проверку условия**."

```
public class Result {
  int mark;

  public Result(String mark) {
    this.mark = (int) (Double.parseDouble(mark) * 10);
  }

  public String getStringMark() {
      return mark / 10 + "." + mark % 10;
    }

  public String toString() {
    return getStringMark();
    }
}
```

Comment: Что же вам мешает поставит условие на остаток деления на 10 и две ветки в методе getStringMark?

Comment: условие задачи мешает, по условию нельзя использовать if

Comment: тернарный оператор используй

Comment: Реализовать отображение, т.е. строковое представление оценки в ООП–стиле, а не через проверку условия.

Answer (score 1):

В вопросе следовало уточнять, что без if нужно сделать.
Вот вариант решения через строки.

```
    public String toString() {
        return (mark / 10 + "." + mark % 10).replaceAll("\\.0", "");
    }
```

Получаем строку из целой части + "." + дробная часть. 
Выкидываем часть с ".0".

Comment: Мне кажется, что ООП - это создание дополнительных веток в классе Result, на месте препода я бы спросил а где тут ООП?

Comment: запихнуть тело метода в toString() и будет отображение объекта без if.